# Are there alternatives to memcpy when I have allocated too much buffer space?

Tags: c

Imagine this simple piece of code. Here I allocated too much memory and I want to only keep the right amount of bytes (to for example send over the network).

```c
char src[100];
    
// Some code that only fills the buffer with 20 bytes
size_t sz = 20;
    
char dest[sz];
memcpy(dest, src, sz);
```

Is there a better way to do this instead of using memcpy?

Comment: The question is not clear. Send over network only the required number of bytes. How is it related to `memcpy` ? If you want to *allocate* only the right amount of memory, then use dynamic allocation (i.e. `malloc`).

Comment: You have not allocated any memory -- you have reserved 100-bytes of storage for `src` which has *automatic storage duration*.. With `sz`, you create a VLA (*variable length array* - only optionally supported from C11 on) and copy `src` to `dest` (which you do not show). It doesn't matter if `src` is `100` or `100000`, the `src` buffer should be sized to accommodate the longest string you anticipate (and double that). Don't skimp on buffer size. You are worrying about micro-optimization here. Get your code working first, then focus on anything that needs tweaking.

Comment: I actually need the optimization since I am working with resource constrained (IoT) devices.

Comment: If you have a defined worse-case (maximum transmission length) defined, then you should allocate it and that's it, optimizing it won't help anyway in that worse-case. What you definitely *should not* do on such a device is to use VLAs, as the stack is tending to be the most constrained resource in such a systems.

Comment: You need to show real code. The code you've shown (apparently inside of a function) just wastes space with the `dest` buffer. Both the `src` array, and the `dest` array are on the stack, and both are removed when the function returns.

Comment: Why do you need a new buffer being exactly 20 bytes. Whatever you are going to do, just do it using the first 20 bytes of src

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Here I allocated too much memory and I want to only keep the right amount of bytes (to for example send over the network).

You don't need to resize the memory to send the right amount. [`fwrite`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite) takes how big your elements are and how much to send. Perhaps you're always using the size of the buffer to determine what to send like `fwrite(src, size(src), 1, fp);`.

Instead, only send what you need.

```
// Only send the first 20 bytes of src.
fwrite(src, 20, 1, fp);
```

> I actually need the optimization since I am working with resource constrained (IoT) devices.

You're not saving any memory, you're using more memory.

Because you're using automatic memory `src` lives on until the end of the block. If you copy `src` to `dest` you're using 120 bytes instead of 100.

Comment: Huh, I didn't even think about that last part. Indeed I end up using even more memory. Now I also understand why a lot of functions take the size parameter in C. No copy needed.

Comment: @SenneVerhaegen C functions take a size parameter because they do not know how much memory has been allocated. Being able to use `size` is a special case for automatic memory, the compiler knows how much you allocated in your scope, but once you pass the pointer to a function it does not. This is why it is so easy to corrupt memory in C, it's very easy to "walk off" the end of your allocated memory. Some functions, like strings, will read until they see a null byte. If you forget the null byte its very easy to walk off the end of a string.

Answer (score 0):

OP's code is OK, when compiler supports *variable length arrays* and array needs did not grow.

```
char src[100];
size_t sz = 20;
char dest[sz]; // VLA
// memcpy(dest, src, sz);
memcpy(dest, src, sizeof dest); // Better when not a char array
```

In C, once an array is *defined*, its size cannot change.   So  `src[]` must remain with 100 elements, but `dest[]` may differ.

---

Alternative: memory allocation via `*alloc()` and friends.

```
size_t sz = 100;
char *src = malloc(sizeof *src * sz);
if (src == NULL) Handle OutOfMemory();

sz = 20; 
char *src_new = realloc(src, sizeof *src_new * sz);
if (src_new == NULL) Handle OutOfMemory();

src = src_new;
// memcpy() not needed as copying done by realloc()
// With a size increase, new elements are indeterminate.

free(src);
src = NULL;
```

---

A 3rd approach is to do more work and determine size needed before defining the array.

```
int size = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s %g %d", some_string, some_double, some_int);
assert(size >= 0);
char s[size + 1u];

size = snprintf(s, sizeof s, "%s %g %d", some_string, some_double, some_int);
assert(size >= 0 && (unsigned) size < sizeof s);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If your object has static or automatic storage class its size cannot be changed runtime.
2. 

> Is there a better way to do this instead of using memcpy?

`memcpy` novadays is the most efficient way of copying the data. Modern compilers know this function very well and usually replace the call to it with inlined efficient code.

example: https://godbolt.org/z/1GKea7Mon